# ¿Como incluir un archivo.php con include dependiendo el resultado de una condición?

Tags: php, mvc, php7

estoy haciendo una validación con una sentencia if para incluir un determinado archivo, dependiendo de el resultado de la condición si es true incluye lo si es false incluye el otro, pero es ignorada la sentencia if aun cuando llega la variable trae el valor true aun así me incluye los dos, mi duda es que si ¿Es valido esto?,¿Se puede hacer? este es el código:

```
 <?php



      if (isset($_POST['bandera'])) {

       // code...

      include '../models/usuario.php';

      }else{

       include 'models/usuario.php';

       }



class UsuarioController{

//codigo

}

?>
```

Comment: En tu código, antes de los if, si haces un var_dump($_POST['bandera']) cuál es el resultado de eso?

Answer (score 0):

Es válido lo que estas haciendo, no sé si tu problema sea de rutas, pero debería de marcar error en tal caso.

Te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['bandera'])){
    $var = '../models/usuario.php';
}
else{
    $var = 'models/usuario.php';
}
 include($var);
?>
```

Comment: Bandera trae valor true, implementare tu consejo

Comment: El isset sólo revisa que exista, no importa el valor que traiga. Si quieres comprobar el valor entonces debería ser: if (isset($_POST['bandera']) && $_POST['bandera'] == TRUE)